# Autogenerate timestamp in EF 6 (Code first): conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data is an out-of-range value

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a class inherited from this:

```
 public abstract class BaseEntity 
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }


    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

But when I try to persis instance (where I do not set `CreatedAt`) it fails with error:

```
{"The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: See if this blog post will help you out and give a good explanation on what is happening. http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/229/conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in-an-out-of

Comment: @AlinaVinnichek you should post a summary as an answer for the credit. It helped me to know that there are plenty of ways to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

First create a base entity:

```
public class Student: BaseEntity
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public decimal Height { get; set; }
    public float Weight { get; set; }
}

public class BaseEntity{ 
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }    
}
```

Then in your db context override the `SaveChanges()` method.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var entries = ChangeTracker
        .Entries()
        .Where(e => e.Entity is BaseEntity && (
                e.State == EntityState.Added
                || e.State == EntityState.Modified));

    foreach (var entityEntry in entries)
    {
        ((BaseEntity)entityEntry.Entity).UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;

        if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            ((BaseEntity)entityEntry.Entity).CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

That's it. I have taken this example from [here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/faq/set-created-and-modified-date-in-efcore.aspx). Have a look there for more details.

Comment: This is a nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

It's because SQL has a different date range, just add this annotation and you'll get rid of the error message:

```
[Column(TypeName="datetime2")]
```